# Xamarin multiple flyouts in one page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, flyout, xamarin.forms.shell

I've been looking at Xamarin.Forms Shell.  The flyout available in Shell by default allows a slide from the left side of the screen or a tap on the toolbar menu button to have the flyout appears on the left side of the screen.

I've also seen a variation of this, where the toolbar and flyout are flipped, so the toolbar button and flyout are on the right side of the screen.

My question is - I want to have multiple flyouts available on the screen.  Shell works, but it APPEARS that I can only have one flyout if I use Shell (either the left or the right, but not both).  Is there a way to use multiple flyouts with Shell?

Or, is there a better solution using something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SideMenuViewPage` from [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit), it is already available but not documented yet.

You may find the full sample of the code below in [SideMenuViewPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/SideMenuViewPage.xaml)

### Sample

```
<xct:SideMenuView x:Name="SideMenuView">
        <!-- MainView -->
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gold">
              <Label Text="This is the Main view" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- LeftMenu -->
        <StackLayout
            xct:SideMenuView.Position="LeftMenu"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuWidthPercentage=".5"
            xct:SideMenuView.MainViewScaleFactor=".95"
            BackgroundColor="Orange">

              <Label Text="This is the left menu view"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- RightMenu -->
        <StackLayout
            xct:SideMenuView.Position="RightMenu"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuWidthPercentage=".3"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuGestureEnabled="False"
            BackgroundColor="LightGreen">

              <Label Text="This is the Right menu view"/>
        </StackLayout>

</xct:SideMenuView>
```

#### Available properties

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `MenuWidthPercentage` | Set the width percentage of your menu relative to it parent. |
| `MainViewScaleFactor` | Set the scale percentage which MainView will be scaled to when a side menu (left or right) is opened. |
| `Position` | Specifies position whether it is right or left or main, if not specified it will be considered as the MainView. |
| `MenuGestureEnabled` | Enable/Disable side swipe gesture option to open/close menu/view. |

### Open/close side menu views (flyout)

#### From code

Left and right menus/views are opened either by swiping gesture or by setting the property `State` of the `SideMenuView` that you defined in your xaml:

```
SideMenuView.State = SideMenuState.MainViewShown;    //show main view and close both left and right menu view
SideMenuView.State = SideMenuState.RightMenuShown;   //Open right menu view
SideMenuView.State = SideMenuState.LeftMenuShown;    //Open left menu view
```

#### From xaml

By default left and right menus are closed (default value of `State` property is `MainViewShown`), if you want initially to have a menu opened, change it value in your xaml:

```
<xct:SideMenuView x:Name="SideMenuView" State="LeftMenuShown">
```

A mixed approach would be to bind `State` to a property and change it in your code according to your logic.

#### Note

For now it is supported for iOS and Android only (**not supported for uwp**).

Comment: wow, that's great, I'll try this out.  This is not something I've seen before.  Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: You're welcome, if you'll find an issue while implementing it let me know, or if you in future you got an idea that might improve it you can open an issue on [GitHub: XamarinCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit).